# Conditional combined indexes：When there are several decimal types of indexes, the desired results can not be queried

Tags: xquery, exist-db

Use version：4.5.0

db/system/config/db/test/collection.xconf The code is as follows：

```
<range>
        <create qname="item">
            <condition attribute="name" value="number"/>
            <field name="number" match="@value" type="xs:decimal"/>
        </create>
        <create qname="item">
            <condition attribute="name" value="acreage"/>
            <field name="acreage" match="@value" type="xs:decimal"/>
        </create>
        <create qname="item">
            <condition attribute="name" value="radii"/>
            <field name="radii" match="@value" type="xs:decimal"/>
        </create>
        <create qname="item">
            <condition attribute="name" value="diameter"/>
            <field name="diameter" match="@value" type="xs:decimal"/>
        </create>
    </range>
```

[Browse Indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRHWg.png)

db/test The code of an XML file is as follows：

```
<root>
<item name="number" value="4"/>
<item name="acreage" value="5"/>
<item name="radii" value="6"/>
<item name="diameter" value="7"/> </root>
```

Query statement：

```
//item[@name='radii'][@value>5.0]
```

[Query Profiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSzDW.png)

No result

In theory, the XML file can be found, but the result can not be found for what? Can you help me? Thank you！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation for eXist's Conditional Combined Indexes feature you are trying to use here, it appears to me that this feature only support string comparisons (with an optional "numeric" mode). See https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/newrangeindex#D3.21.18. In other words, your `@type="xs:decimal"` is not resulting in your attributes' values being cast to `xs:decimal`; effectively, instead, they are being indexed as `xs:string`.

Thus, for your query to work with the given data, change the predicate to `[@value gt "5"]`.

Or, to force numeric comparisons, add `numeric="yes"` to the `<field>` element in your index definitions, and then change your predicate to `[@value gt "5.0"]`.

Comment: The creator of this feature confirmed my understanding: https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/pull/1233#issuecomment-454300328. I would say the situation could be improved to be sensitive to the declared `@type`, but for now my suggestion is a usable workaround.

Comment: How do I achieve ambiguous matching in range index queries

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I've got what I want. Thank you for your help.